# Django and Reactjs: complex templates

Tags: javascript, django, reactjs

I've been looking for this question for a while and still not quite clear. What approaches you use to build templates for Django application using Reacjs? How do you show different menus for authorized and not authorized users? Is it possible to keep html layout in .html file and just render Reactjs components in required places? How to communicate between those components?

Here's for example:

I have a page like this, with menu, and list of items:

```
<body>
    <div>
        {% if not user.authenticated %}
            <a href="/login">Login</a>
        {% else %}
            <a href="/logout">Logout</a>
            <a href="#">Add item</a>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
    <ul>
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

If user is not authorized i show a button "Login" in it, otherwise there are two buttons: "Logout" and "Add item". When i click "Add item" button i need to open modal window with form. On form submit i want to append item to `<ul>` list. This is just example, page can contain a lot of html markup. The questions above.

Please ask in comments if my question is not clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are a bit confused, if you are using react ( or any other js framework for single page app) you shouldn't use the django template to render some part ( even though you can ). The logic to show or not the login should be in the react template, not in the django template. For example: 
Django template

```
<head>
<script>
 var userInfo = {
   authenticated : {% user.authenticated %}
   // add anyother user info
 }
</script>  
<head>
<body>
  <div id="app"/>
</body>
```

JS application:

```
var React = require("react");
var Component = require("./components/Login");

function render(element, id) {
  React.render(<Login/>, document.getElementById(id));
}

render(Component, "app");
```

Login:

```
var React = require("react");

var Login = React.createClass({

  renderLogin: function () { 
     var loginButton;
     if (userInfo.authenticated) {
       loginButton = <LogoutButton />;
     } else {
       loginButton = <LoginButton />;
     }
     return loginButton;
  }


  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="Login">
        {renderLogin}
    </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

module.exports = Login;
```

I wound't just access the global variable from any react component, rather I would access it from the root componenent and then propagate it down to the children components by means of props or context.